# How can I save the state of pagination in a NodeJS + Express + Jade app?

Tags: node.js, express

I have list of items in a page with pagination. Let's say, I am in the page 10 and I want to edit an item.

After I click the update button, this code is run:

```
  res.redirect('back')
```

But this redirects me to the same page, not the last one.

What is the best way to do it with pagination?

Comment: query string parameters ?

Comment: parameters in url - ie: /pg/10, ?pg=10. Or do the update inline with ajax, so they never leave the current page. But if you're adding things, the pagination should change.